# How to match absolutely all cases in Node JS Regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string `"first case" something very important "other case"` and regex `"(.*?)"`. When I am using

```js
const string = '"first case" something very important "other case"';
const regex = /"(.*?)"/g;

const matches = string.matchAll(regex);

for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

it doesn't match `" something very important "` but I need it. How can get it?
(P.S. Sorry for my English)

Edited: I will use regex for `string.replace(regex, func)` but maybe I will try to implement your solution and `string.replace` will disappear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an easy question and  IMO anyone could figure it out. By asking Stack Overflow you have lost the opportunity to find the answer on your own and grow. If you worked for me I would have you go to https://regex101.com/ until you figured it out.

Comment: @nzajt I am beginner on regex, doesn't know advanced things about it. Because this I asked about it here. I'm self-taught, usually I see source code and after some time I can understand it and on this base do my self things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use of the `(?=...)` syntax which is called the **positive lookahead** that will use the character defined in it again for the next match.

In addition to the non capturing group `(?:...)` syntax.

All explained below :

---

https://regex101.com/r/q5SxDr/1

[image]

---

```js
const string = '"first case" something very important "other case"';
const regex = /(?:")(.*?)(?=")/g;

const matches = string.matchAll(regex);

for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(`${match[1]}"`);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, regex is good, but it doesnt includes last symbol `"`. It needs because I will use that regex for replace. I forgot to said it in post(?). Will change it!

Comment: @DMax Do you need to get `first case"` or `"first case"` ?

Comment: I need to get `"first case"`

Comment: If you replace `"first case"` using a replace. You won't be able to match `" something very important"` anymore because there is one `"` that is used by both!

Comment: Thanks, I found solution to implement your solution

Answer (score 1):

To provide a non-regex solution, you can simply split on `"` and then filter out empty strings (where quotes were used at the beginning or end of a string). Doing a non-regex solution will generally provide greater understanding in 6 months when you come across your "old" code.

```js
const string = '"first case" something very important "other case"';

const matches = string.split('"').filter(s => s !== '');

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with lookarounds to allow all matches:

```js
const regex = /(?<=")(.*?)(?=")"/gm;
const str = `"first case" something very important "other case"`;
let match;

while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```